# asp.net parses wrong numeric values as 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

When passing a wrong or empty value to a numeric parameter it gets parsed as 0.
e.g. if you call something like this -> /api/getValue?id=abc

and id is an int, id will have a 0 value instead of throwing an exception.

The same would happen if the call had an empty value -> /api/getValue?id=

Any way to make this error throw an exception instead of it passing the wrong value to the method?

BTW, using a nullable int makes you unable to use a parameterless overload so it isn't a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
     if(!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         return BadRequest();
     }
     return Ok();
}
```

The `ModelState.IsValid` will be false if a non numeric value has passed as parameter. You can throw an Exception inside the if-statement if you wish.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Silly me, I have used ModelState.IsValid a lot of times when working with MVC and I completely forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following method:

```
int my_query;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]) && int.TryParse(Request.QueryString["id"], out my_query))
{
// do something!
}
```

Hope it helps.